# child objects don't move as expected

Tags: parent

My scene has a number of child cylinders that have a plane parent object.  When I rotate the parent (plane), all the child cylinders move as expected - as if they are attached and resting on the plane.  When I try to move one of the child cylinders, it instantly moves off to a seemingly random position.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: Could you provide a .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: Gladly.  But I see there isn't a way to upload a file.

Comment: Forgot I had a dropbox account.  Hopefully you can access it.

Comment: I've downloaded your file and I was able to grab and of the cylinders and position it any place I want as shown here http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=110848 what version of blender are you using?

Comment: Currently using version 2.78a

Comment: Well, I don't understand what happened - I tried myself and the objects are moving as you described - so I don't know if I changed something or if something in the animation has something to do with it.

Comment: That appears to be the problem, the animation.  If it is not at frame 1, then it behaves unexpected when I move a parent object.  Thank you for checking into it.

Comment: not a problem, I'm glad I was able to help. I've added an answer so if you can accept and upvote it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into your file, this is caused because there is an existing animation starting from frame 1.